# Resize border of qgraphicstextitem

Tags: resize, border, pyqt6, qgraphicstextitem

I am adding a QGraphicTextItem to a scene using pyqt6.
I cannot resize the widget border when text is resized.
I have looked at a few way of resizing, but none work.
The text does change to a bigger font via the context menu.
The entire class is shown below.

```
class FreeTextGraphicsItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, text_):
        super(FreeTextGraphicsItem, self).__init__(None)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text = text_
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable |
                      QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsFocusable |
                      QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.font = QtGui.QFont(self.settings['font'], 9, QtGui.QFont.Weight.Normal)
        self.setFont(self.font)
        self.setPlainText(self.text)
        self.setPos(self.x, self.y)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction(_("Large font"))
        action = menu.exec(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        if action is None:
            return
        if action.text() == "Large font":
            self.font = QtGui.QFont(self.settings['font'], 12, QtGui.QFont.Weight.Normal)
        frame = self.document().documentLayout().frameBoundingRect(self.document().rootFrame())
        self.boundingRect().setRect(0, 0, frame.width(), frame.height())

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        color = QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.white
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color, style=QtCore.Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        painter.setFont(self.font)
        fm = painter.fontMetrics()
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.black))
        lines = self.text.split('\\n')
        for row in range(0, len(lines)):
            painter.drawText(5, fm.height() * (row + 1), lines[row])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *not* using the features of QGraphicsTextItem.
In fact, you're completely ignoring and overriding most of its aspects:

- `x` and `y` are existing and dynamic properties of all QGraphicsItems and should never be overwritten;
- the same for `font` of QGraphicsTextItem;
- calling `setRect()` on the bounding rectangle is useless, as `boundingRect()` is a *property getter" and is returned internally by the item based on its contents (in this case, the text set with `setPlainText()`);
- the text drawing is completely overridden, and not reliable nor consistent with the text set for the item, considering that you're painting the text with split lines, while the original text has escaped new lines;

If your main purpose is to draw a border around the item, then you should only do that, and then rely on the existing capabilities of the item.

```py
class FreeTextGraphicsItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, text_):
        super().__init__(text_.replace('\\n', '\n'))
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setFlags(
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsFocusable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable
        )
        font = QtGui.QFont(self.settings['font'], 9, QtGui.QFont.Weight.Normal)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setDefaulTextColor(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.white))

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        largeFontAction = menu.addAction(_("Large font"))
        action = menu.exec(event.screenPos())
        if action == largeFontAction:
            font = QtGui.QFont(
                self.settings['font'], 12, QtGui.QFont.Weight.Normal)
            self.setFont(font)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        painter.restore()
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)
```

Note: comparing actions with their text is pointless, other than conceptually wrong; not only you can have a more reliable object-based comparison using the action (as shown above), but that comparison can also become invalid: a menu could contain items that have the same names, and you're also probably using the `_` for translations, so the text might not match at all.